# Data in Array of earlier pocket is being deleted

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Dim n As Integers
Public AAA() As Integer
Public QQQ() As String

Sub Initialise()
n = 0
End Sub

Sub WrongAnswer(oShape As Shape)
A = oShape.TextEffect.Text
SendWrongAnswer
End Sub

Sub SendWrongAnswer()
ReDim QQQ(500)
QQQ(n) = Q

ReDim AAA(500)
AAA(n) = A

n = (n) + 1
End Sub
```

When I make the array `AAA()` and `QQQ()` and store data in the pockets, the data in earlier pockets becomes "0" or "".

If `AAA(1) = 50` and then when the macro stores `AAA(2) = 34`, then `AAA(1)` becomes 0.

Comment: The `Redim` statement sets all values in the array to zero.= if the array contains integers or null string if the array is of string type. All values assigned to elements of teh array prior to the `Redim` statement will be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `ReDim` statement to `Sub Initialise` method then it will work.

```
Sub Initialise()
n = 0
ReDim AAA(500)
ReDim QQQ(500)
End Sub
```

EDIT: If you want to preserve the existing data when you redimension it then use `preserve` keyword.

```
ReDim Preserve AAA(500)
```

Comment: Is it possible for the number of pockets (500) to be according to the number of questions they manage to answer? Or it has to be defined? Can't we make new pockets on the go?

Comment: First get the number of questions answered then use the same in `AAA(size)`. If size is to be calculated at run time and at the same time you want to use array also then you can use `preserve`. Check my updated answer.